# when i dragged mouse the object start at different position

Tags: java, mouselistener

when i dragged mouse the object start at different position,

i want start both mouse position and object ceter position have same position
starting.

ive tried some ways and couldnt find solution in google.
so i put up question.

```
package math;

 import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class movingButton extends JFrame {

     private JButton button;

     public movingButton() {
         super("Position helper");
         super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         super.setSize(500, 520);
         super.setVisible(true);
         super.setLayout(null);
         button = new JButton("drag me ");
         add(button);
         button.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 40);


         button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

             public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent E) {

                 int X = E.getX() + button.getX();
                 int Y = E.getY() + button.getY();
                 button.setBounds(X, Y, 150, 40);

             }
         });
     }


 }



 public class Main {

     public static void main(String args[]) {

         new movingButton();


     }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subtract the position where the button was clicked from your new X and Y position of the button. You can get these by adding a `MouseListener` with a `mousePressed` method to your button. I think it would become easier if you create a new class that extends from `MouseAdapter` to combine both methods.

```
public movingButton() {

    [...]

    MouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter(){
        int mouseClickedPosX = 0;
        int mouseClickedPosY = 0;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent E){
            mouseClickedPosX = E.getX();
            mouseClickedPosY = E.getY();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent E){
            int X = E.getX() + button.getX() - mouseClickedPosX;
            int Y = E.getY() + button.getY() - mouseClickedPosY;
            button.setBounds(X, Y,150,40);
        }
    };

    button.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
    button.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ArcticLord